# Invoking one component from another component through Button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Getting below error while clicking on button

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:TestRateCard$controller$callMe [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:TestRateCard$controller$callMe}

```
 <!-- Component One : TestRateCard-->

<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,force:appHostable" access="global" >
     <aura:attribute name="accId" type="String" access="global"/>
    Component One
    <lightning:button label="Create Case"  onclick="{!c.callMe }" />
</aura:component>
```

```
({
callMe  : function(component, event, helper){
            console.log('Enter Here');
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToMyComponent");
        console.log('Event '+evt);
        var accountFromId = component.get("v.accId");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef  : "c:TestRateCardTwo" ,
            componentAttributes : {
                accountId : accountFromId
            }
        });    
        evt.fire();
}
})
```

```
<!-- Component Two : TestRateCardTwo-->

<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,force:appHostable" access="global" >
        <aura:attribute  name="accountId" type="String" access="global"/>

    Second Component

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written `var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToMyComponent");`

where as it should be :- `var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");`

See the difference **navigateToMyComponent** and **navigateToComponent**. There is no such event with name **navigateToMyComponent** in Aura Framework.

Read the docs here:- [Navigate To Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToComponent/documentation)

Ideally, you should use [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`lightning:isUrlAddressable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) Interface to navigate the component, You can also pass the attributes. **Note : component will open in new tab**

> The `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface extends the
>   `lightning:hasPageReference` interface. A component that implements
>   lightning:isUrlAddressable then gets access to the page state through
>   the pageReference attribute. The page state is a representation of the
>   current URL query parameters.

Starting in API version 43.0, the force:navigateToComponent event is deprecated as per the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToComponent/documentation)